Can you add an exit code prefix in the bash PS1?
While customizing my Bash, I tried adding an exit code prefix to the PS1 variable (I set it in .bashrc). It would print the exit code of the last command before displaying the new line.
My initial code was something like PS1="Process exited with code $?\n..."
While this approach mostly works, an annoying side effect is that it also gets printed on the line displayed when bash is started. This results in an annoying "Process exited with code 0" getting printed every time you start bash.
Screenshot 
Expected behavior
I have tried a couple methods, including a self-overriding variable _exitcode="\$(_exitcode=\"...\")", a counter and an if statement _commands=0; PS1="\$(let _commands++; if [ $_commands > 1 ]; then echo ...)" and using the $LINENO environment variable.
None of these approaches worked.
This is the relevant code (full code on github):
# Set up prompt
_exitcode () {
    if ! [ $LINENO = 0 ]; then 
        if [ $1 = 0 ]; then
            echo -en "\e[90m"
        fi;
        echo "Process exited with code $1"
    fi
}
PS1="\e[0m\
\$(_exitcode \$?)
\e[91m\u\e[33m@\e[34m\H\e[0m \
\$(_pWd)\
\$(_suffix)"

Edit: I found a solution myself using the PROMPT_COMMAND variable with a counter. Code - Changes

I found that duplicate instantly by googling "bash show exit code in prompt".
